# Finding the minimum of a Numpy array of (x,y) cordinates

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Numpy array of (x,y) coordinates similar to the one shown bellow:

```
points=np.array([[ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 2.00000000e+00, -2.97422935e-07],
       [ 4.00000000e+00, -3.29450278e-06],
       [ 6.00000000e+00, -7.52036485e-06],
       [ 8.00000000e+00, -1.81746526e-05],
       [ 1.00000000e+01, -3.18379179e-05],
       [ 1.20000000e+01, -4.59500442e-05],
       [ 1.40000000e+01, -5.98470188e-05]])
```

In order to plot these points, I need the minimums and the maximums of the x values and the y values separately.
I used a for loop for this purpose.
For example, to find the minimum x values:

```
x_min = points[0,0]
for kk in range(len(points)):
    if x_min>points[kk,0]:
        x_min = points[kk,0]
```

But I would like to know whether there is a better way of doing this..
Appreciate your help

Comment: Use the built-in min and max functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built-in [min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) & [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
min(points[:,0]) # giving you 0.0
min(points[:,1]) # giving you -5.98470188e-05
```

and

```
max(points[:,0]) # giving 14.0
max(points[:,1]) # giving 0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Python's builtin `min` and `max` will certainly work, but Numpy has [its own versions](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.04-computation-on-arrays-aggregates.html) which run much more efficiently.

```py
x_min, y_min = points.min(axis=0)
x_max, y_max = points.max(axis=0)
```